# UseEnpoints with MapHub returns expects unit but has type HubEndpointConversationBuilder

Tags: f#, signalr

I'm trying to try out SignalR with F# and create a simple chat (Tutorials everywhere)

But when I add

`.UseEndpoints(fun routes -> routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub"))`

to my **configureApp** I get error

`UseEnpoints with MapHub returns expects unit but has type HubEndpointConversationBuilder`

All the exempels I been looking into is using the function like this.
Any ideas?

Using .NetCore 3.1
and ChatHub function looks like this.

```
type ChatHub() =
  inherit Hub()
  member x.SendMessage user msg =
    task {
      do! x.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, msg)
    }
```

````
let configureApp (app : IApplicationBuilder) =
    let env = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IHostEnvironment>()
    (match env.IsDevelopment() with
    | true  -> app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()
    | false -> app.UseGiraffeErrorHandler errorHandler)
        .UseHttpsRedirection()
        .UseCors(configureCors)
        .UseStaticFiles()
  Error--->.UseEndpoints(fun routes -> routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub")) 
        .UseGiraffe(webApp)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MapHub` is a side-effecting operation, returning an object for further, fluent configuration. `UseEndpoints` however expects nothing, i.e. `unit`.

```
.UseEndpoints(fun routes -> routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub") |> ignore)
```

should fix this. This 'fix' is often needed for glueing the OO-side-effect world to the functional one. Beware the dragons:

```
.UseEndpoints(fun routes -> routes.MapHub<ChatHub> |> ignore)
```

will happily compile but probably not do what’s intended.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. this removed the error. got another problem, but at least I am one step further to goal :)